# Не получается соединить пути при помощи os.path.join()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь соединить пути в системе при помощи os.path.join()
У меня есть класс, в который приходит параметр '\icons'
И он ни как не присоединяется к пути root в self.sorting_path

```
class SortingFiles:
    def __init__(self, sorting_pat):
       self.root_path = os.getcwd()
       self.sorting_path = os.path.join(self.root_path,sorting_pat)
       self.end_path = os.path.join(self.root_path, 'icons_by_year')
       self.files = {}
       print(self.files)
       print(self.sorting_path)
       print(self.root_path)
```

Вот что, выводят принты:

```
{}
C:/icons
C:/Users/bluntwave/PycharmProjects/python_base/lesson_009
```

Comment: @nomnoms12 Проблема с sorting_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема в лидирующем слеш - такой путь join начинает строить от корня первого пути, т.е. если убрать лидирующий слеш (вместо `\icons` передать `icons`) то все будет работать.

```
import os

root_path=r'c:\dummy\root\path'
path_with_slash=r'\target'
path_without_slash='target'

print(os.path.join(root_path,path_with_slash))    # c:\target
print(os.path.join(root_path,path_without_slash)) # c:\dummy\root\path\target
```

Comment: Спасибо, огромное!!!!!